# How to solve this specific bug in a memory like game built with vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to build a website where you can mix elements to create new elements, a bit like little alchemy.
For example `fire` + `stone` = `lava`.
It is built with cue

Right now, everything is working fine, except there is one bug:
When you do `air` + `air` it equals `wind` (this is good). And when you do `water` + `air` it equals `rain` (this is good as well). But when you do `air` + `water`, it says that it is not a good mix.

It is a very specific subject and it is pretty hard to explain.

This is my code:

```
<template>
  <button
    v-for="element in myElements"
    :key="element"
    @click="firstInput = element"
  >
    {{ element }}
  </button>
  <br />
  <button
    v-for="element in myElements"
    :key="element"
    @click="secondInput = element"
  >
    {{ element }}
  </button>
  <h2>{{ firstInput }} + {{ secondInput }} = {{ nameResult }}</h2>
  <datalist id="elements">
    <option
      v-for="element in myElements"
      :key="element"
      :value="element"
    ></option>
  </datalist>
  <br />
  <button @click="checkInList">Check</button>
  <!-- <h1>{{ nameResult }}</h1> -->
  <h1>Attention: don't refresh</h1>
  <div v-for="element in list" :key="element">
    <h2>{{ element.name }}</h2>
    <div v-for="creation in element.elements" :key="creation">
      <div v-if="myElements.includes(element.name)">{{ creation }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <test-component /> -->
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
// import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent.vue"

export default {
  name: "App",
  // components: {
  //   TestComponent,
  // },
  setup() {
    const firstInput = ref("");
    const secondInput = ref("");
    const elementsResult = ref("");
    const nameResult = ref("");
    const result = ref("");
    const myElements = ref(["water", "air", "stone", "fire"]);

    const list = ref([
      { name: "mountain", elements: ["stone", "stone"] },
      { name: "lava", elements: ["stone", "fire"] },
      { name: "wind", elements: ["air", "air"] },
      { name: "rain", elements: ["air", "water"] },
      { name: "volcano", elements: ["lava", "mountain"] },
    ]);

    const listNames = ref([]);
    list.value.forEach((element) => listNames.value.push(element.name));

    const checkInList = () => {
      const values = [firstInput.value, secondInput.value];
      values.every((value) => {
        result.value = list.value.filter((x) => x.elements.includes(value))[0];
      });

      elementsResult.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.value)).elements;
      console.log(elementsResult.value);
      const arrayEquals = (a, b) => {
        return (
          Array.isArray(a) &&
          Array.isArray(b) &&
          a.length === b.length &&
          a.every((val, index) => val === b[index])
        );
      };

      // console.log(
      //   Array.from(nameResult.value) == [firstInput.value, secondInput.value]
      // );
      console.log(
        arrayEquals(elementsResult.value, [
          firstInput.value,
          secondInput.value,
        ]) ||
          arrayEquals(elementsResult.value, [
            secondInput.value,
            firstInput.value,
          ])
      );
      if (
        arrayEquals(elementsResult.value, [
          firstInput.value,
          secondInput.value,
        ]) ||
        arrayEquals(elementsResult.value, [secondInput.value, firstInput.value])
      ) {
        // console.log(elementsResult.value)
        nameResult.value = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.value)).name;

        // console.log(firstInput.value, secondInput.value)
        if (!myElements.value.includes(nameResult.value)) {
          myElements.value.push(nameResult.value);
        }
      }
    };

    return {
      firstInput,
      secondInput,
      checkInList,
      myElements,
      nameResult,
      list,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Please help me out if you know an answer.